# how to enable pretty print option for Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, pretty-print

I have a minified js file I need to put a break point on. In chrome and IE 11 I have the option to pretty print, but in Edge I can't see the pretty print option.

Do I need to able the pretty print option in options or somewhere, or does Edge not have that option.

I searched on Google, but it all shows the Chrome and IE 11 methods. I didn't find a related article for Edge pretty printing.

Note: {} - pretty print for chrome and IE 11 working perfectly.

What I tried

1. Open Edge
2. Press f12 find the min file
3. checked the response body

didn't seen an "{}" icon

Comment: Microsoft Edge is different from Internet Explorer; they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 12):

For Edge, check left bottom corner.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's there. Here's a screen shot. It's the small icon with the brackets and lines in between

[Pretty Print ICON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHMtS.png)

Comment: It doesn't work for large js files though. Edge 44.18362.449.0, Windows 10.